# -bash: pkcs12: command not found

Tags: osx, openssl

I am trying to export the private key and certificate to p12 file using below command in my mac os X - Mountain Lion:

```
pkcs12 -export -out privkey.pem -inkey privkey.pem -in rsaCert.crt
```

but I am getting this error:

> -bash: pkcs12: command not found

To verify if it is there or not, I typed below man command:

```
man pkcs12
```

which is showing appropriate manual page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The above line looks like being from `openssl`.

pkcs12 is a subcommand of openssl. You probably mean:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out privkey.pem -inkey privkey.pem -in rsaCert.crt
```

Your man page probably also tells you to use `openssl pkcs12`.

Comment: This is correct.  Also, @Miraaj's command would _also_ be correct if the user was actually in the OpenSSL _shell_ by first executing the `openssl` command from their Bash prompt.  However, the typical thing to do is to just execute it all from Bash by adding `openssl` before the command itself.